# Use data from variable in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a function like this (value is from select):

```
function getSelectValuePower () {
 var power = document.getElementById("power").value;
  sessionStorage.setItem("power", power);
  console.log(power);
}
```

How can I use value from variable power in another function ?
For example :

I want to use it here :

```
function getValue () {
  var number = 10;
  var selectedValue = number + power;
  console.log(selectedValue2);
}
```

So, when my power is 7, the result in getValue() should be 17.

I tried to do it with global variables, but doesn't work.

Comment: *"I tried to do it with global variables, but doesn't work."* - Yes it does, unless something else is wrong that isn't described here.  If the variable needs to be visible in a higher scope then you'd move its declaration to a higher scope.  Which **might be** "global", depending on where these functions are declared.  Can you demonstrate your attempt with a runnable [mcve]?

Comment: Taking another look after seeing the answer below... You're storing the *value* of `power` in session storage.  Why do you specifically need the *variable* `power` in the other function?  Why not just read the value from session storage?

Comment: Yes, now I see it. It will be the best option, thanks.!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get power in second function:

```
var power = sessionStorage.getItem("power");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `parseInt()` as well

```js
function getValue() {
  const number = 10;
  const power = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("power")) || 0;
  const selectedValue = number + power;
  console.log(selectedValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by declaring power outside the function or by creating a class. Here's how you can do it.

Using global declaration:

```
var power = document.getElementById("power").value;
function getSelectValuePower() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("power", power);
    console.log(power);
}

function getValue() {
    var number = 10;
    var selectedValue = number + power;
    console.log(selectedValue);
}
```

Using a class:

```
class PowerSelector {
  constructor() {
    this.powerElement = document.getElementById("power");
    this.number = 10;
  }

  getSelectValuePower() {
    const power = this.powerElement.value;
    sessionStorage.setItem("power", power);
    console.log(power);
  }

  getValue() {
    const selectedValue = Number(this.number) + Number(this.powerElement.value);
    console.log(selectedValue);
  }
}

const powerSelector = new PowerSelector();
powerSelector.getSelectValuePower();
powerSelector.getValue();
```